# I am trying to take a user input and display

Tags: c#

This is my code. I am trying to take a user input and display a `FoodItem`, but the way I have done it only allows for one input to be entered without doing lots of "or" statements in the while loop. Also to print the profile based on an input. Is there any way to print this multiple time?

```
namespace excercise_4_week_6
{
    class Program
    {
        double totalCost;
        string inputString = "";

        void run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==++     Food Menu     ++==");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the item you would like to order: ");

            Console.WriteLine();

            FoodItem Pizza = new FoodItem("Pizza", "Margherita Pizza", 4, 9.99);
            FoodItem Burger = new FoodItem("Burger", "Burger with Cheese and chips", 1, 8.99);

            while (inputString == "" || inputString == Pizza.Name)
                {
                    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    if (inputString == Pizza.Name)
                    {
                        Pizza.PrintFoodProfile();
                        totalCost = totalCost + Pizza.Cost;
                        Console.WriteLine("The total cost is: £" + totalCost);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Program excercise_4_week_6 = new Program();
          excercise_4_week_6.run();
       }
    }

    public class FoodItem
    {
        string name;
        string description;
        int numberServed;
        double cost;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }

        public int NumberServed
        {
            get { return numberServed; }
            set { numberServed = value; }
        }

        public double Cost
        {
            get { return cost; }
            set { cost = value; }
        }

        public FoodItem(string name, string description, int numberServed, double cost)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.numberServed = numberServed;
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public void PrintFoodProfile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Description: " + description);
            Console.WriteLine("The number of people this serves: " + numberServed);
            Console.WriteLine("Cost: £" + cost);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Your question implies you are considering two alternatives. Can you show the code for the two alternatives because I'm not sure where you are heading with this application.

Comment: I think you need to look into the switch statement  rather then using if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your food items into a dictionary:

```
var foodItems =
    new Dictionary<string, FoodItem>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

foodItem.Add("Pizza", new FoodItem("Pizza", "Margherita Pizza", 4, 9.99));
foodItem.Add("Burger", new FoodItem("Burger", "Burger with Cheese & chips", 1, 8.99));
```

Now you can find food items by name like this:

```
FoodItem foodItem;
if (foodItems.TryGetValue(userInput, out foodItem)) {
    Console.WriteLine(foodItem.Name);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("not found!");
}
```

You can loop through all the food items like this:

```
double totalCost = 0;
foreach (FoodItem foodItem in foodItems.Values) {
    totalCost += foodItem.Cost;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1:0.00}", foodItem.Name, foodItem.Cost);
}
Console.WriteLine("Total cost = {1:0.00}", foodItem.Cost);
```

If you only need to loop through the food items, but don't have to look up single items by name, then adding the food items to a `List<FoodItem>` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Comment: `var totalCost = foodItems.Values.Sum(foodItem => foodItem.Cost);`

Comment: Are lambda expressions and extension methods known in excercise 4 week 6?

Answer (score 0):

you want remove while?

instead of

```
 while (inputString == "" || inputString == Pizza.Name)
  {
      inputString = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine();

      if (inputString == Pizza.Name)
      {
          Pizza.PrintFoodProfile();
          totalCost = totalCost + Pizza.Cost;
          Console.WriteLine("The total cost is: £" + totalCost);
          Console.WriteLine();
      }
  }
```

use this

```
    if (inputString == Pizza.Name)
   {
       Pizza.PrintFoodProfile();
       //get NumberServed
       Pizza.NumberServed = Console.ReadLine();
       totalCost = Pizza.NumberServed * Pizza.Cost;
   }
   else if (inputString == Burger.Name)
   {
       Burger.PrintFoodProfile();
       //get NumberServed
       Burger.NumberServed = Console.ReadLine();
       totalCost = Burger.NumberServed * Burger.Cost;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The total cost is: £" + totalCost);
```

for remove while

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still need the while to be able to loop round and check for an input multiple times in order to get a total cost of everything ordered.

Comment: you get `numberServed` and then cost=numberServed*Pizza.Cost;